# Firefox doesn't play audio after playing through HDMI

Tags: sound, firefox, pulseaudio, hdmi

After playing firefox audio through an HDMI device it doesn't play through other devices.
I am able to fix the problem  each time is occurs by using this:

```
rm -r ~/.config/pulse; pulseaudio -k
```

Is there a permanent solution to this problem?

Comment: Please add `pactl list short sinks`  when the situation appear.

Comment: 0 alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1b.0.analog-stereo module-alsa-card.c s16le 2ch 48000Hz SUSPENDED
1 alsa_output.pci-0000_00_03.0.hdmi-stereo module-alsa-card.c s16le 2ch 48000Hz SUSPENDED

Answer (score 0):

Okay, similiar to my Problem.  In `.config/pulse/default.pa`  comment string `load-module module-suspend-on-idle` with `#` out. If the file doesn't exist you can copie it `cp /etc/pulse/default.pa ~/.config/pulse/default.pa` this avoids that sound sink suspends. It stays  `

> Disconnects sinks and sources from their backend after a predetermined amount of idle time. Idle time is accumulated when the sink/source in question is not connected to any streams. Disadvantages: When pulseaudio gives up the backend, and the backend is not capable of mixing, errant applications can grab the sound device and hold exclusive control over it, making pulseaudio stop working. If pulseaudio does not give up the backend, errant applications won't be able to play sound, but they will not disrupt pulseaudio's operation either. This scenario is possible 99% of the time, since most users run an ALSA sink/source without a card that has software mixing. An "errant application" would, for example, try to open hw:0 or front:0 rather than the 'default' ALSA device.

For more info [pulseaudio modules](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/PulseAudio/Documentation/User/Modules/#index64h3)